# Removing last character of JSON object

Tags: python, json

I'm looking for a way to remove the last character of a line of JSON, provided it's not a curly brace.

I've a whole file of JSON but for some reason some of the lines end with a few spaces and then a 0. I'm trying to remove the 0 if it appears, or skip that line if it doesn't.

For example: Ignore this:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
    ]
  }
}}
```

And remove the 0 from this:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
    ]
  }
}} 0
```

I've tried using:

```
line = line.rstrip('0')
```

But it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: By "line", do you really mean a line of text? For example, could there be a `0` after `"file",`? And what happens if the JSON is formatted in a weird way, so there's a `0` at the end of a line, but the `0` is actually part of the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
re.sub(r'0$', '', line)
```

Comment: Never ceases to amaze me how quickly you can get answers on here. Thanks, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it does not work, because you have the last character is not `0` but `\n` or `\r\n`.
So, you need

```
line = line.rstrip().rstrip('0')
```